# QGIS 3 save project to geopackage

Tags: qgis-3

I am saving all layers of my map to a geopackage. This works fine so far. Now I want to save my project into the same geopackage.  I select Project Save to Geopackage and now QGIS 3.8.3 (OS: windows 10) crashes.
What I am doing wrong?

```
Crash ID: d5e7e232839b5a6635b925b3cc3c6c55a1c54cfe


Stack Trace


QString::multiArg :
QString::arg :
QgsGeoPackageProjectStorage::writeProject qgsgeopackageprojectstorage.cpp:241
QgsProject::write qgsproject.cpp:1799
::operator() qgisapp.cpp:14525
QMetaObject::activate :
QAction::activate :
QMenu::actionGeometry :
QMenu::actionGeometry :
QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent :
QWidget::event :
QMenu::event :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:403
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:403
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
UserCallWinProcCheckWow :
DispatchMessageWorker :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main main.cpp:1567
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :




QGIS Info
QGIS Version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar
QGIS code revision: 685d8b15d2
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2
Running against Qt: 5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL: 2.4.1
Running against GDAL: 2.4.1



System Info
CPU Type: x86_64
Kernel Type: winnt
Kernel Version: 10.0.18362
```

Comment: look at this issue https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31967

Comment: My geopackage is not empty, it contains already all geometry-data and these geometry-data are ok. My problem is, I cant save/add the project-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gone in QGIS 3.10. So the solution is to upgrade to the new qgis 3.10.